# Poisson Disc Sampling Throws Index Out Of Range

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, poisson, indexoutofrangeexception

here's Poisson Disc Sampling Algorithm realization that I use:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace Assets.Scripts.Algorithms
{
    public static class PoissonDiscSampling
    {
        public static List<Vector2> GeneratePoints(int seed, float radius, Vector2 sampleRegionSize, int sampleAmount)
        {
            Random.InitState(seed);
            float cellSize = radius / Mathf.Sqrt(2);
            var grid = new int[Mathf.FloorToInt(sampleRegionSize.x / cellSize), Mathf.FloorToInt(sampleRegionSize.y / cellSize)];
            var points = new List<Vector2>();
            var spawnPoints = new List<Vector2>
            {
                sampleRegionSize / 2
            };

            while (spawnPoints.Count > 0)
            {
                int spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Count);
                Vector2 spawnCenter = spawnPoints[spawnIndex];
                bool accepted = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < sampleAmount; i++)
                {
                    float angle = Random.value * Mathf.PI * 2;
                    var direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle), Mathf.Cos(angle));
                    Vector2 candidate = spawnCenter + direction * Random.Range(radius, radius * 2);

                    if (IsValid(candidate, sampleRegionSize, cellSize, radius, points, grid))
                    {
                        points.Add(candidate);
                        spawnPoints.Add(candidate);

                        grid[(int)(candidate.x / cellSize), (int)(candidate.y / cellSize)] = points.Count;

                        accepted = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!accepted)
                {
                    spawnPoints.RemoveAt(spawnIndex);
                }
            }

            return points;
        }

        private static bool IsValid(Vector2 candidate, Vector2 sampleRegionSize, float cellSize, float radius,
            IList<Vector2> points, int[,] grid)
        {
            if (candidate.x >= 0 && candidate.x < sampleRegionSize.x && candidate.y >= 0 && candidate.y < sampleRegionSize.y)
            {
                int cellX = (int)(candidate.x / cellSize);
                int cellY = (int)(candidate.y / cellSize);
                int searchStartX = Mathf.Max(0, cellX - 2);
                int searchStartY = Mathf.Max(0, cellY - 2);
                int searchEndX = Mathf.Min(cellX + 2, grid.GetLength(0) - 1);
                int searchEndY = Mathf.Min(cellY + 2, grid.GetLength(1) - 1);

                for (int x = searchStartX; x <= searchEndX; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = searchStartY; y <= searchEndY; y++)
                    {
                        int pointIndex = grid[x, y] - 1;

                        if (pointIndex != -1)
                        {
                            float sqrDistance = (candidate - points[pointIndex]).sqrMagnitude;

                            if (sqrDistance < radius * radius)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But there's a slight problem with this algorithm realization. On the line:

```
grid[(int)(candidate.x / cellSize), (int)(candidate.y / cellSize)] = points.Count;
```

After few iterations it throws

> Index Out Of Range Exception

Somehow (I am still not sure why) It goes beyond the size of the `grid`, sometimes it can be negative and sometimes it can be basically equal the size of the `grid`.

I'm stuck and I don't know what to do. It seems that there's something that I simply don't see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume `cellSize` is 1 and `sampleRegionSize.X`  is `10.9`. This would result in a grid of size `10`. `candidate.X` must be less than `sampleRegionSize.X` to be valid, but `10.8` would be fine. Cast it to int and you would end up with `10`. Since arrays are zero indexed `10` will be out of range.

Moral of the story; do not trust floating point math. If you need to convert a floating point coordinate to an index, check that the index is valid before trying to use it. There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014) [articles](https://floating-point-gui.de/) [on the](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [dangers](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/the-dangers-of-using-float-or-real-datatypes) of floating point math.